# Iterate the data dynamically using Tiny Slider JS

Tags: javascript, html, object, tiny-slider

I have array of objects that includes name and description. My goal here is to display the name and description dynamically in my image carousel with the help of Tiny Slider js.

I try the following attempt but failed.

1. Use `.getElementById()` to get the slider element and `.map()` to render the data inside the object but unfortunately the whole data was rendered in one slider only.

The actual result:
[image]

**index.html**

```
                   <div id="sliderCont" class="my-slider">
                        <div>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <div class="slide-img" style="background-image: url('src/images/img-1.jpg')">
                                    <a href="http://">View More</a>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="slide-info">
                                    <h3 id="project-name"></h3>
                                    <p id="project-description" class="subtext"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
const project = [
  {
    image: "",
    name: "Project 1",
    description: "Project Description here.",
  },
  {
    image: "",
    name: "Project 2",
    description: "Project Description here. 2",
  },
  {
    image: "",
    name: "Project 3",
    description: "Project Description here. 3",
  },
  {
    image: "",
    name: "Project 4",
    description: "Project Description here. 4",
  },
];

document.getElementById("project-name").innerHTML = project.map((proj) => proj.name);
document.getElementById("project-description").innerHTML = project.map((proj) => proj.description);
```

**Tiny Slider Config**

```
let slider = tns({
  container: ".my-slider",
  slideBy: 1,
  speed: 200,
  nav: false,
  controlsContainer: "#controls",
  prevButton: ".previous",
  nextButton: ".next",
  preventScrollOnTouch: "auto",
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayButtonOutput: false,
  responsive: {
    1600: {
      items: 4,
      gutter: 20,
    },
    1024: {
      items: 3,
      gutter: 20,
    },
    768: {
      items: 2,
      gutter: 20,
    },
    480: {
      items: 1,
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
project.map((proj) => proj.name)
```

...returns an array:

```
["Project 1", "Project 2", "Project 3", "Project 4"]
```

When assigning this array to `document.getElementById("project-name").innerHTML` it is converted to the string `"Project 1,Project 2,Project 3,Project 4"`.

So you're essentially assigning this string to the `.project-name` `innerHTML`value:

```
document.getElementById("project-name").innerHTML = "Project 1,Project 2,Project 3,Project 4";
```

The same thing happens with:

```
document.getElementById("project-description").innerHTML = project.map(
    (proj) => proj.description
);
```

---

Instead, first iterate, [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), over the `project` array, and in the loop block add a slide.

To create multiple slides use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to copy the `.slide` DIV. (Since you're duplicating this DIV and it's child nodes, don't use IDs. Use class names instead: `.project-name` and `.project-description`.) And append the new node to the `.slide`'s [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

After the `project` array loop is exited, remove, [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild), the original `.slide-info` DIV.

```js
const project = [
  {
    image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random?w=200",
    url: "p1.html",
    name: "Project 1",
    description: "Project Description here."
  },
  {
    image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random?w=200",
    url: "p2.html",
    name: "Project 2",
    description: "Project Description here. 2"
  },
  {
    image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random?w=200",
    url: "p3.html",
    name: "Project 3",
    description: "Project Description here. 3"
  },
  {
    image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random?w=200",
    url: "p4.html",
    name: "Project 4",
    description: "Project Description here. 4"
  },
];

// get target DIV, containing .slide-img, .project-url, .project-name, and .project-description
const slide = document.querySelector(".slide");

// iterate over project array
project.forEach(proj => {

  // make a clone of .slide for new slide
  const newslide = slide.cloneNode(true);

  // add image background to .slide-img div
   newslide.querySelector(".slide-img").style.backgroundImage = `url('${proj.image}')`;

  // add url href to .project-url anchor tag
  newslide.querySelector(".project-url").href = proj.url;

  // add name to .project-name header
  newslide.querySelector(".project-name").innerHTML = proj.name;

  // add description to .project-description paragraph
  newslide.querySelector(".project-description").innerHTML = proj.description;
  
  // add slide to .slide parent
  slide.parentNode.appendChild(newslide);
});

// remove original slide
slide.parentNode.removeChild(slide);
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-img">
            <a class="project-url" href="" style="color: white;">View More</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="slide-info">
            <h3 class="project-name"></h3>
            <p class="project-description subtext"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fortunately, it does work in my code sir, it shows the list but the whole slider doesn't work.

Comment: One problem down, one more to go. If this solves the problem in your question, please accept my answer, that way others will know it works. And then post another question about your tiny-slider not working.

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. I also iterate the image using this code `   newSlide.querySelector(".slide-img").style.backgroundImage = `url(${proj.image})`;`

Comment: Inspired by your adventurous spirit I expanded my answer. :)