# Tiny Slider JS doesn't work when using Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, javascript-objects, tiny-slider

[My current problem in this question was solved,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72678386/iterate-the-data-dynamically-using-tiny-slider-js) to iterate the data dynamically using Array of Objects.

Now the problem here is the rendering of data using Tiny Slider JS. I rendered it in the HTML code but unfortunately, it doesn't follow the slider UI.

**The actual result:**

[image]

**app.js**

```
const project = [
  {
    image: "src/images/img-1.jpg",
    name: "Project 1",
    description: "Project Description here.",
  },
  {
    image: "src/images/img-2.jpg",
    name: "Project 2",
    description: "Project Description here. 2",
  },
  {
    image: "src/images/img-3.jpg",
    name: "Project 3",
    description: "Project Description here. 3",
  },
  {
    image: "src/images/img-4.jpg",
    name: "Project 4",
    description: "Project Description here. 4",
  },
];

const slide = document.querySelector(".slide");
project.forEach((proj) => {
  const newSlide = slide.cloneNode(true);

  newSlide.querySelector(
    ".slide-img"
  ).style.backgroundImage = `url(${proj.image})`;

  newSlide.querySelector(".project-name").innerHTML = proj.name;
  newSlide.querySelector(".project-description").innerHTML = proj.description;

  slide.parentNode.appendChild(newSlide);
});

slide.parentNode.removeChild(slide);
```

**index.html**

```
                    <div class="my-slider">
                        <div>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <div class="slide-img" style="background-image: url('src/images/img-1.jpg')">
                                    <a href="http://">View More</a>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="slide-info">
                                    <h3 class="project-name"></h3>
                                    <p class="project-description subtext"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Tiny Slider Config**

```
let slider = tns({
  container: ".my-slider"
  //...options here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The rendering in Tiny Slider.js does not work because of excess div tags outside the slide class.

Final structure of **index.html**:

```
                       <div class="slide">
                            <div class="slide-img">
                                <a href="http://">View More</a>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="slide-info">
                                <h3 class="project-name"></h3>
                                <p class="project-description subtext"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```